Did I solve this Spivak (Calculus, Prologue) problem correctly?
Question:
If $|y-y_0|\lt \frac{|y_0|}{2}$ and $|y-y_0|\lt \frac{\varepsilon|y_0|^2}{2}$ then $y\neq 0$ and $|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}|\lt \varepsilon$
Solution:
First we shall prove $y\neq 0$ which is trivial as it follows directly from the equation $|\frac{y-y_0}{y_0}|\lt \frac{1}{2}$ Secondly, utilizing the property $|x|<a\leftrightarrow -a<x<a$ we see that $(|\frac{y}{y_0}-1|\lt \frac{1}{2})\longrightarrow (\frac{1}{2}<\frac{y}{y_0}<\frac{3}{2})$ from this we derive $|\frac{y}{y_0}|>\frac{1}{2}$. Multiplying ($|\frac{y}{y_0}|>\frac{1}{2}$) by  ($|\frac{y-y_0}{y_0}|<\frac{\varepsilon|y_0|}{2}$). We arrive at $|\frac{y-y_0}{y_0y}|<\varepsilon\longrightarrow |\frac{1}{y_0}-\frac{1}{y}|<\varepsilon$. Utilizing the identity $|a|=|-a|$. We complete our proof that $$|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}|<\varepsilon$$ Q.E.D

Show the details of your inequality work. I think your multiplying and arriving at are quite suspicious.

Your steps of "multiplying" and "arriving" do not seem to follow. Also, a more direct argument is possible.
You have $\def\e{\varepsilon}$
\begin{align}
\bigg|\frac1y-\frac1{y_0}\bigg|
&=\frac{|y_0-y|}{|yy_0|}
\leq\frac{\e y_0^2}{2|yy_0|}=\frac{\e|y_0|}{2|y|}<\e,
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows from
$$
|y_0|-|y|\leq|y_0-y|<\frac{|y_0|}2,
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\tag{*}
\frac{|y_0|}{2}<|y|
$$
and so
$$
\frac{|y_0|}{2|y|}<1.
$$
Incidentally, $(*)$ shows that $y\ne0$ if $y_0\ne0$, and $y_0\ne0$ follows from the first inequality $|y-y_0|<\frac{|y_0|}2.$

When you say my steps don't follow are you saying they're incorrect or are you saying they don't imply each other?

I cannot tell, because I don't know which two inequalities you are multiplying. What I do know is that multiplying inequalities is unusual.

OK, I understand I made an edit to my original post to make it more clear which inequalities I was multiplying. Additionally, while my work above is admittedly convoluted because I am inexperienced, I still don't understand if my work is actually correct or not. Please tell me. Thanks!

Yes, what you did is correct, but the way it is written is  hard to follow (particularly because you wrote one of the two inequalities to multiply in reverse form, and you don't discuss the manipulatios that follow; concretely that after multiplying you have to multiply both sides by $2/|y|$). In my answer you can see how to use the same idea but without multiplying inequalities.

Please upvote if you found the answer useful (not just mine, but also others on the site that are useful to you).

The first inequality implies $$\left |{y\over y_0}-1\right |<{1\over 2}$$ Thus ${y\over y_0}>{1\over 2},$ Hence $${|y_0|\over2|y|}<1$$The second inequality implies $$\left |{1\over y_0}- {1\over y}\right |<\varepsilon{|y_0|\over 2|y|}$$ Combining two inequalities gives the conclusion.
